# Where are typesetting shortcuts like :sub: defined?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In particular, is there a way to add a shortcut like `:nsub:` to `\[NotSubset]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `\[NotSubset]` the default alias is `⋮!sub⋮`. 
Of course, as mentioned in HPMark's answer, if you're not happy with that you can either change the `InputAliases` for the current Notebook:

```
oldOpts = InputAliases /. Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> Append[oldOpts, "nsub" -> "\[NotSubset]"]]
```

Or, probably a better approach is to use the Option Inspector to add the alias to either the current Notebook or the Global Preferences (it's in the Editing Options section). 
The latter changes the `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m`.

Comment: Also, the `Notation` package has the command `AddInputAlias` (`⋮addia⋮`) -- but you probably don't want to load the notation package each time.

Comment: Actually I found that command useful for defining input aliases for "current session" -- AddInputAlias[stuff, "in", #] & /@ Notebooks[];

Comment: @Yaroslav That usage is different from the documentation center -- what exactly does it do?

Comment: it's equivalent to the form that lets your specify target notebook

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where the intrinsic ones are defined, but it seems that you can add your own using [InputAliases](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputAliases.html).

Comment: @rcollyer: yes, it was new to me too.

Comment: Yeah, they are not something you come across that easily. I learnt about these when I was given some really old notebooks that didn't have the `⋮dintt⋮` alias (and others) that I was so use to.